# Apache Camel maximumReconnectAttempts still reconnecting

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using apache camel with spring boot.

I configured a route with maximumReconnectAttempts=0 when trying to connect to a local sftp server on my machine.

I started my spring boot application while keeping the sftp server stopped, but the route it still trying to reconnect more than  time (at this level, I expected an exception or something like that or closing the connexion ...) until I started the sftp server and then the files were transferred

This is my route configuration:

```
from("sftp://tester@192.168.1.23:22??noop=true&password=password&maximumReconnectAttempts=0").to("file:C:/Users/aminos/Desktop/serverData");
```

and this is the log

```
2021-11-02 11:39:20.213  INFO 14372 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   :     Started route1 (sftp://tester@192.168.1.23:22)
2021-11-02 11:39:20.213  INFO 14372 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.11.1 (camel-1) started in 207ms (build:35ms init:157ms start:15ms)
2021-11-02 11:39:20.229  INFO 14372 --- [  restartedMain] com.camel.springboot.Application         : Started Application in 3.62 seconds (JVM running for 4.251)
2021-11-02 11:39:21.230  INFO 14372 --- [192.168.1.23:22] o.a.c.c.file.remote.SftpOperations       : Known host file not configured, using user known host file: C:\Users\aminos/.ssh/known_hosts
2021-11-02 11:39:22.256  WARN 14372 --- [192.168.1.23:22] o.a.c.c.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer   : Cannot connect/login to: sftp://tester@192.168.1.23:22. Will skip this poll.
2021-11-02 11:39:22.769  INFO 14372 --- [192.168.1.23:22] o.a.c.c.file.remote.SftpOperations       : Known host file not configured, using user known host file: C:\Users\aminos/.ssh/known_hosts
2021-11-02 11:39:24.287  INFO 14372 --- [192.168.1.23:22] o.a.c.c.file.remote.SftpOperations       : Known host file not configured, using user known host file: C:\Users\aminos/.ssh/known_hosts
2021-11-02 11:39:25.823  INFO 14372 --- [192.168.1.23:22] o.a.c.c.file.remote.SftpOperations       : Known host file not configured, using user known host file: C:\Users\aminos/.ssh/known_hosts
2021-11-02 11:39:27.364  INFO 14372 --- [192.168.1.23:22] o.a.c.c.file.remote.SftpOperations       : Known host file not configured, using user known host file: C:\Users\aminos/.ssh/known_hosts
2021-11-02 11:39:28.880  INFO 14372 --- [192.168.1.23:22] o.a.c.c.file.remote.SftpOperations       : Known host file not configured, using user known host file: C:\Users\aminos/.ssh/known_hosts
2021-11-02 11:39:30.414  INFO 14372 --- [192.168.1.23:22] o.a.c.c.file.remote.SftpOperations       : Known host file not configured, using user known host file: C:\Users\aminos/.ssh/known_hosts
2021-11-02 11:39:30.599  INFO 14372 --- [192.168.1.23:22] route1                                   : File name : hosts
2021-11-02 11:39:30.615  INFO 14372 --- [192.168.1.23:22] route1                                   : File name : Microsoft Teams.lnk
```

Comment: It would help if you where to post your route configuration as `java-dsl` or `sping-xml`. Use code blocks for **code** and **logs** i.e [three backticks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) which you can use with [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). Use of external links and images is bad because they can become inaccessible after you delete the file or imgur goes down for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

You're using **sftp consumer endpoint** which is a [polling consumer](https://camel.apache.org/components/next/eips/polling-consumer.html) meaning that it'll check the sftp server for new files on specific intervals. The `maximumReconnectAttempts` option is probably meant to be used with producer endpoint or when using [poll enrich](https://camel.apache.org/components/next/eips/pollEnrich-eip.html) pattern to prevent minor connection issues from stopping the exchange.

You can configure the behaviour using [PollingConsumerPollStrategy](https://camel.apache.org/components/next/eips/polling-consumer.html#PollingConsumer-ConfiguringantoUsePollingConsumerPollStrategy) or configure the polling interval with [delay](https://camel.apache.org/components/next/sftp-component.html#_endpoint_query_option_delay) to configure poll intervals or stop the route using [control bus](https://camel.apache.org/components/next/controlbus-component.html) or something on connection related exception.